# SharePoint foundation and Azure service

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, azure

Can SharePoint 2013 Foundation connect to `Azure Services` ? The Purpose of the Azure Service is to integrate SharePoint with salesforce.

Please Help.

Comment: it can be, but what is your requirement, could you please ask more detail about your question